# How to prevent flickering with web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component

Consider a simple web component

```
class TimeAgo extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.innerHTML = '2 hours ago'
    }
}

customElements.define('time-ago', TimeAgo);
```

Being used like this

```
This post was created <time-ago datetime="2020-09-26T11:28:41.9731640+01:00">September 26th</time-ago>
```

When the page renders, the browser will first write "September 26th" and right after that switch to "2 hours ago".

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I'd much prefer to display "2 hours" on first paint.

The JS file is loaded through a CDN, moving the script tag up and down the response didn't change anything.

Comment: related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683430/how-to-stop-fouc-from-happening-with-native-web-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But is your element defined and its script executed before that part of the DOM is parsed?

Code below displays **1A** because the **1** is injected into the DOM **before** *content* **A** is parsed.

So if you don't want a FOUC leave `<time-ago>` **content** empty.. or maybe blur it with CSS

```html
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    console.log("onload");
  };
  customElements.define(
    "my-element",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("constructor");
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        console.log("connectedCallback");
        this.innerHTML = "1";
      }
    }
  );
</script>
<my-element>A</my-element>
<script>
  console.log("end DOM");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer led me to the conclusion. The script I had at the <head> was just creating the custom element but it was not being defined (customElements.define) until a later script that was executed at the bottom of the <body>. moving both up did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solution I can think of is to enable `shadow-dom`

```js
class TimeAgo extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.innerHTML = '2 hours ago'
    }
}

customElements.define('time-ago', TimeAgo);
```

By defining your web component to be shadow dom, you can change the content even before it's attached to the DOM.